# Adding controls to tab page runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controls, tabpage

I am using C# and winForms, I have a few tabcontrols, which contains a few tab pages, 
I would like to add all tab pages my user control, it would be best, If I could add it after user click on tab page. It works for me only, when I add this controls in constructor - what makes delay at application start - about 3 seconds, what is very much.

I would like to add this controls at run time, like

```
tabPage1.onClickEvent()
{
tabPage1.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
}
```

but it didnt works, I also tryied to use Invalidate, or Refresh method but it not works.

So is there any possibility to add this userControls in other method than constructor? 
Maybe its problem, that I have TabControl inside TabControl and I have to add this controls throught parent TabControl? 
Thanks!

Comment: I faced a similar problem and solved it by adding/removing tab pages to the TabControl. Maybe this approach works better for you. Overally, I think that 3 seconds startup is pretty much. Are you sure this is caused by adding controls to a component? Could you go into more detail about what you want to achieve? Maybe it would be even better to have the user control there and just switch the `Visible` property

Comment: what do you mean you have a tabcontrol inside a tabcontrol?  shouldn't you have a tabcontrol with tabpages??

Comment: This delay could be caused because I have 28 tab pages - and every consist of userControl - which is consist of 2-3 userControls, so its pretty much userControls.

Comment: I have main tabcontrol which consist of 2 tabpages - and this tabpages consists of another tabcontrol - which consist of tabpages - where I would like to add controls

Comment: This sounds like a crazy UI design that will be confusing for a user to follow. That being said, @yas4891's idea of creating and setting the visible property to false until you need to display it to the user is a good way to do this (unless you are loading a different set of 28 tabs depending on some other logic).

Comment: @Martin This sounds like something rather 'unconventional' to me. My advise at this point is to do a hallway usability test and see if users can actually cope with this design. You might well find out in the process that users just can't and that you will have to redesign the UI to get your users along

Comment: @yas - that was the same point I was trying to make. A nested tab control with 28 tabs on it is unwieldy. As a developer and fairly savvy user, I still find managing a UI with more than 6 tabs to be quite a chore.

Comment: i did a similar task months ago......i used tabPage selected (or selecting) event. it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try double clicking the tag page in the designer, or you can add the event handler manually like this:

```
tabPage1.Click += new EventHandler(tagPage1_Click);
```

I don't know whether tabPage1 is dynamic, but if it's not, you should add the above event handler to your designer.cs file.

Here is the event handler in the code:

```
protected void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tagPage1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
}
```